# How to get a video from a youtube playlist by count using java?

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I need to get a YouTube video from a playlist.

How do I get the items from a playlist? 
Is there a way of parsing them into a list (so that I'm able to filter a specific video out of it)?
I'm using Java. If you have a good tutorial or some stuff like this I would be really pleased!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation of the YoutubeAPI's `PlayListItems` [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems) and [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#usage).

You can import Google's API [library](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/api-client/google-api-client-assembly/1.23.0/google-api-client-assembly-1.23.0-1.23.0.zip) and use this sample code to call the YoutubeAPI for a specific playlist, and it will return a JSON file with the playlist's information in it.

```
// Sample Java code for user authorization

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;

import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTubeScopes;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.model.*;
import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class ApiExample {

    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "API Sample";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
            System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/java-youtube-api-tests");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/drive-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final Collection<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl YouTubeScopes.https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner");

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = ApiExample.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader( in ));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
                flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println(
                "Credentials saved to " + DATA_STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized API client service, such as a YouTube
     * Data API client service.
     * @return an authorized API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static YouTube getYouTubeService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new YouTube.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        YouTube youtube = getYouTubeService();

        try {
            HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails");
            parameters.put("maxResults", "25");
            parameters.put("playlistId", "PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE");

            YouTube.PlaylistItems.List playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest = youtube.playlistItems().list(parameters.get("part").toString());
            if (parameters.containsKey("maxResults")) {
                playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.setMaxResults(Long.parseLong(parameters.get("maxResults").toString()));
            }

            if (parameters.containsKey("playlistId") && parameters.get("playlistId") != "") {
                playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.setPlaylistId(parameters.get("playlistId").toString());
            }

            PlaylistItemListResponse response = playlistItemsListByPlaylistIdRequest.execute();
            System.out.println(response);


        } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : " + e.getDetails().getMessage());
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In that code, `maxResults` to your desired result size and `playlistId`to the id of the youtube playlist which can be found in the url. (ie the id for this playlist `https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE` is `PLBCF2DAC6FFB574DE`)

Comment: Just one last thing:
When I'm exporting this on my rpi3, it says that I have to authorize it. But the link isnt working, it says: "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" and that "localhost denied this connection", any ideas?

EDIT: Its just not working, after I exported it, when I start it with intellij its fine...

Comment: @MoorhuhnHD I'm not sure why it would refuse the connection. The only thing I can think of is that your credentials change when you export it to your rpi3.

Comment: Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @MoorhuhnHD Launch the application in intellij and find out what the credentials are that are working properly. Then, you can hardcode those credentials into your app. If that doesn't work, just debug your code and see what is different in the two environments.

Comment: Is possible use it with Android Java Native?

Comment: @DjongaNelsonLontrowski Be sure to import the libraries at the top. `import com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTube;` should fix your issue.